# Remove Adware from Installer.exe before Installation

Tags: windows, installation, adware

Malwarebytes detects *PUP.Optional.BundleInstaller.Generic* inside the official [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org/download.php) .exe installer which I want to remove **before** installing it. 
Unfortunately I couldn't find a tutorial to achieve this so I really really hope someone has an idea.

Comment: Your options are to make a donation  to them and they will give you an ad-free installation file, or go with the free version and deal with the advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

Your anti-virus may be detecting the adware offer included in the free
installation, or it may just be a false positive.

Try to run the installer this way :

```
FreeFileSync_9.2_Windows_Setup.exe /nobounty
```

Note that :

1. You may simply decline any adware offer during installation with no harmful
   effects. Just be careful when clicking your way through the installation
   process.
2. Even a small donation will get you adware-free installation for life.
   In my opinion FreeFileSync is worth it.

Comment: I'd really like to have an installer without any Bundleware so that the installation file doesn't disappear if the Anti-Virus or Anti-Malware program get's reconfigured or replaced. It's not about the money. I don't even tried FreeFileSync yet and I'm not ready to do so if there's any chance of an Adware infection!

Comment: I've been using FreeFileSync for years without problems before I decided to donate. It never installs adware without warning, and the "adware" itself is not that harmful.

Comment: Donations are currently not enabling life-time ad-free updates. A year of ad-free updates currently costs EUR50.

Comment: @TheDiveO: The license has changed, but the year license is now pay-as-you-want.

Comment: https://www.freefilesync.org/faq.php#donation-edition says EUR25 per year, I don't see anything else on the site. In fact, for paying 5EUR all I got was 6 weeks free update. I have no problem supporting, but this is bleeding.

Comment: @TheDiveO: On the 26-01-2018 I made a 2.00 EUR donation and got a yearly license. That's all I know.

Comment: I just did a donation these days (thursday or so) and all I got for EUR5 was 6 weeks. So, FreeFileSync isn't exactly playing open here, me thinks.

Comment: @TheDiveO: Well, the free version can be installed without the adware. But if this is no longer true, there are many other such free utilities - see [link](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-folder-synchronization-utility.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The installer downloaded from the link https://www.freefilesync.org/download.php has many malwares. Here is the [VirusTotal report](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/f4bc63977a182fcce758b08603ee03983b6353aa243e0de7bb550b12d936847e/detection) of that 9.3 Windows installer. The installer is an **[Inno Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup)**.   It can be configured to use as standalone. Here are the two process to do it.

- ### With command line tool::

Extract it with [Inno Setup Unpacker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/innounp/) command line tool. Download and put innounp.exe and FreeSync installer both in same folder. Then open command prompt and type `innounp.exe -x FreeFileSync_installer.exe` to extract the files from that installer. You may find the main executable file FreeFileSync.exe in {app} folder.

[image: Innounp Command to extract]

- ### With graphical tool::

Open the installer in **[Inno Extract](http://constexpr.org/innoextract/#download)** GUI tool just by drag & drop the installer in it. Click on the extract button and select the folder where you want to extract those files. Remember to *merge the RegistrySection.reg* registry file to configure the file type. Now run FreeFileSync.exe

[image: Inno Extract GUI Tool]

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Command line tool extraction does work but if I execute "FreeFileSync.exe" Windows says that the installation media is damaged "Can't open `\{app}\Install.dat`". As you can see "Install.dat" is in fact missing. But if I execute "RealTimeSync.exe" it opens without issues. Besides that, where is the "RegistrySection.reg" file?

Comment: The GUI innoextract.exe just pops up a window which disappears within milliseconds. Too fast to see what's happening... Even if started with admin privileges.

Comment: I clicked on the link for the GUI you gave me, downloaded "innoextract-1.6-windows.zip", extracted it to a new folder with 7-Zip and double klicked on "innoextract.exe". A window pop ups and disappears within a second. That's all. I tried to run it as admin, same. Tried to run it in compatibility mode (Win 7), still the same... :/

Comment: Sorry I gave wrong link. See this link http://www.havysoft.cl/innoextractor.html. I'll update it in my answer.

Comment: I added "RegistrySection.reg" to the registry but still the same error. "Install.dat" is missing.

Comment: May be that file is created only when you install it in regular way. The file name written in install_script.iss file. You may get that file from a regular install in Roaming folder.

Comment: I installed it inside a VM and copied the "Install.dat" which was located inside `C:\ProgramFiles\FreeFileSync` not `\AppData\Roaming` but now it says that the program was installed on a different system.

Comment: Ok then, you have to install it first in your PC. That install.dat file may be programmatically connected. I quit  :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a portable version without this problem:

[Official (6.2)](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/freefilesync-portable)

[Alternative (10.17)](https://www.teamos-hkrg.com/index.php?threads/freefilesync-for-windows-version-10-17-portable-teamos.84337/) (no guarantees) (I raised it to [virus total](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d6c6bb5bcdc722045026289b4726a7827122162732f16d956a02fa43468ccbfa/detection))